# SQL Error 1064 - Import Error

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I exported a database as a backup that was working fine. When I imported the database to the same exact server, folder, etc. I got this error:

> There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser.
>   Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are
>   correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be that
>   you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area.
>   You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. The
>   MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in
>   diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser
>   fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your
>   SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a
>   bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:
>   ----BEGIN CUT---- eNo1jUEKwjAURIXu/inmADHkpwYxu1JCu0iTmFQ9gYtushP09qaCs3oMjxmXc8wWI2PU8C5YMDSY
>   qayt7oiWT7l6CyON7NWxV5LpVjJiERgmF1aBu2vmY6sY5xwX11Ql9YXSMlicGhtKc9otEcs+1Es+
>   w2/19SY/hMniWen3Qd3hny8nMiDI
>   ----END CUT----
>   ----BEGIN RAW---- ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 11 STR:
>
> MySQL: 5.5.30-30.1 USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win CHROME 5.0.29 PMA: 4.0.5
>   PHP VER,OS: 5.3.17 Linux LANG: en SQL:
>   ----END RAW----
>
> SQL query:
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

The only problem seems to be that my index page is missing content, the main content actually. All of these files are .sql.

I then dropped all my tables and imported the original database from April of last year. Obviously, this database is missing all the account info, order info, etc. for all my customers as well as all the changes that have been made to my products.

When I compare the two databases the first 11 lines seem to be the problem but I don't know how to fix it. The first 11 lines of the file that DO NOT WORK are:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Sep 22, 2013 at 01:28 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.30-30.1
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

The first 11 lines of the file that DOES WORK are:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 09, 2012 at 05:50 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.61
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

I hve tried to simply copy and paste the 11 lines from the working file to the file that does not work and get another error.

I know this is a long post and I apologize but I have been struggling with this for hours and really need some help.

Thanks

Comment: SQL_MODE was added in version 4.1 and your version is 3.4.10.1

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out below.

Answer (score 19):

OK, so here is what I found, finally. When I opened the file that was giving me the error in notebook+, the last line, of course, had the following:

ETXNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL

The original working database when opened did not have any of these characters.

When I simply deleted the last row of the file that was giving me the error and imported the database, everything worked fine. However, my homepage was still not being pulled up properly. I applied a workaround for now and will try to figure that out later.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: it work, however, i wondering if it was the .sql file's generating's faults? thank you!

Comment: I had the same ETXNULNUL.. line at the end of my sql file. Removing it did the trick.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem too with the ETXNULNULNUL characters.  Software versions used for export are: MySQL: 5.5.32-cll, phpMyAdmin: 4.0.5, PHP: 5.3.17.  Looking at everyone else's posts it looks like a common denominator is PHP 5.3.17.

Comment: Yep, same thing for me, getting rid of the last line in the sql file solved this issue!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when exporting my database for a Joomla 2.5 site.
It has something to do with the compression in phpmyadmin.
I changed the compression from "none" to "zipped" before exporting the database and that solved it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I need to change compression to **NONE** and SQL compatibility mode to **ANSI**. I was exporting WordPress database to the another server.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there are a bunch o reasons that could trigger this error. I just wanted to share my problem and the workaround i found for it, hopefully it would save someone some time.
I too encountered this problem while trying to import a database to MySql. I had exported a version of a database from my local machine and i wanted to import it to the server where my website is hosted. problem was that there was a mismatch between the versions of the two systems.
I managed to get around the problem by using the compatibility option(both while exporting and while importing). i used "MYSQL323" . This fixed my problem. 
I think this is a good solution for those who have the possibility to make a fresh exported version of the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in phpMyadmin

Here is a temporary fix

http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4095/#7e0c

or something like that:

replace "PMA_Response::getInstance()->disable();" "//PMA_Response::getInstance()->disable();" -- /path_to_phpMyAdmin/export.php

Answer (score 0):

I`ve fixed this error 1 minute before.
When you export sql.gz file, try to extract it.
The extracted file is still compressed bu *.sql file.
Try add again *.sql.gz And import the renamed file.
it will work.

What i`m trying to say, that phpMyAdmin compress the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:
comment

```
;mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

in 
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem importing a CSV file and figured out that the issue was that i had some empty columns from excel conversion and when i selected the first line as column names to import, it tried to create several columns without apropriate unique name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a blank line at the end of the dump file. Removing the line fixed my issue.

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.