# Import database backup return #1064

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

Suddenly importing database backup returns the error below.
The odd thing is that importing an old working copy it works.
If I export it straight afterwards and I try to re-import it the file gives this error.

Looks like it's PhpMyAdmin export that causes issue.
Is there any change in PhpMyAdmin export process that I'm not aware of?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004101/sql-error-1064-import-error) looks like my problem but the solution didn't work for me.

```
There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. 
Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are 
correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be 
that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text 
area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. 
The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also 
help you in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or 
if the parser fails where the command line interface succeeds, please 
reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, 
and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:

----INIZIO CUT----
eNo1jU0KwjAYRIXuvlPMAWIw0SrNLoTQLvJn0roXF1IQ3Sjo7U0FZ/UYHjM255gVjICRcDYoCEgI
QWWsdUPkP+XoFFou+L5b3x5XmkpGLAy6t2FkONkq+vMFZsjR22puuOwoea2wq9xSGtJisViWnS0X
B7j5/nqT06FXmJ/0u6Bm9c8XSs4hPQ==
----FINE CUT----

----INIZIO RAW----
ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 11
STR: MySQL: 5.1.69-log
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Mac CHROME 5.0.29
PMA: 4.0.5
PHP VER,OS: 5.3.17 Linux
LANG: it
SQL: 

----FINE RAW----



Query SQL:

Messaggio di MySQL: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

(I translated what I could in the error as my phpmyadmin is in Italian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an outdated phpMyAdmin version. I believe that the fix mentionned in https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4095/ (for the upcoming 4.0.8 version) will help you.

Direct link to the fix (can be applied to 4.0.7): https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/b717657de77db0b58179bdbdd88e23d0fc3d7ea6

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the solution. Open the sql document with any code editor and at the very end in the last line you will see some black strange codes just delete and save should work as it worked for me.

I'm not sure how and why this code been generated when I exported my database.

Comment: Good find, this is the quickest workaround to the issue.

Comment: At the end of my sql dump, three blank lines were created. Removing them all the DB upload