# mysql error after imoprting all tables

Tags: mysql

i have exported database with 500 tables and import to another server all tables imported successfully but in last it throws some error like...

There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser.
Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are 
correct and not mis-matched. Other possible   failure causes may be
that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area.
You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. 
The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you 
in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser
fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL
query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a bug 
report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:

```
----BEGIN CUT----
eNo1jU0LgkAYhANv76+Yg0ddehUj9rbIYsLq2q4adO4DIeySUP++NWiY0/DMjHbOOomSUWYwupVg
ZGAm34c4IvJjyOL6ElPz8UcjUYhC5Hn6eN5p8A7WJ1CVbvsEow6V0zSjsefaGBXQLXWNksgE8+qc
ukO3con16xKLHcw0L28yqq0krnO6vG7pnn5PFG3++gLS2iXH
----END CUT----
----BEGIN RAW----
ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 11
STR: 
SVN: $Id$
MySQL: 5.5.33-log
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win MOZILLA 5.0
PMA: 2.11.11.3
PHP VER,OS: 5.1.6 Linux
LANG: en-utf-8
SQL: 
----END RAW----
SQL query:
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '' at line 1
```

Comment: Post the code of line 1..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import database backup return #1064](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095033/import-database-backup-return-1064)